# Random error iterating add fields (multiple) to folder of shapefiles

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, iterator

I have a folder of shapefiles in iterating through and a series of processes. I am getting several seemingly random errors, between which field is the issue or on which shapefile it happens to, mostly at the add field (multiple) process but not always. I have made it through my model for several of the files but never completed the entire folder of ~10 shapefiles.

I've attached pics of a 3 I had in short succession that are the most common but I've received 00208, 00601, 000728 as well.[image: Error 000852][image: Error 000852 #2][image: Error 000210]

Update: 11/13/23
The file is not locked or in use anywhere else, I validate and save before every run and this happens inconsistently among different fields and shp's. Whether I delete a previous version or not, it does not change the outcome.

I've made some updates to my model layouts, Mode3 is a submodel of Model1. I am still getting the randomized errors as well as not getting the shp's into the GDB for some reason.[image: Model1][image: Model3]

I am at wits end. Surely, I am missing something simple.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information than this.  But the "Cannot add field" error is described at the link in the error message.  The most likely cause is that the Shapefile is in use and therefore locked.  For the other error, again the listed causes included file locking.  You will need to rule those out first.

Comment: You might also consider working with file geodatabase instead (less kludgey, more types, smaller size, better performance).

Comment: Is it possible that the feature class and field already exists from a past iteration? Your last error looks like it's pre-existing and either locked or your environment overwrite output is false. As @SonofaBeach said though, it's most likely that it's got a lock from another process.

Comment: Are you writing to data in a dropox/onedrive/google drive location? If so, don't! read/write from c:\ drive.